# Form Validation is not Working

Tags: javascript, forms

Form validation not working due to using value="" attribute in form.
Can anyone please suggest me any way to validating form with current validation code with using value="" attribute in form.

HTML Code-

```
<form action="email.php" method="post" name="contactForm" id="contactForm" onsubmit="return validateForm();">
    <input type="text" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Name'){this.value = '';}" onblur="if(this.value == ''){this.value='Name';}" id="Name" value="Name" name="name">
    <input type="text" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Company'){this.value = '';}" onblur="if(this.value == ''){this.value='Company';}" id="Company" value="Company" name="company">
    <input type="text" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Email'){this.value = '';}" onblur="if(this.value == ''){this.value='Email';}" id="Email" value="Email" name="email">
    <input type="text" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Phone'){this.value = '';}" onblur="if(this.value == ''){this.value='Phone';}" id="Phone" value="Phone" name="phone">                        

    <span>
        <input type="text" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Geo Targeting'){this.value = '';}" onblur="if(this.value == ''){this.value='Geo Targeting';}" id="GeoTargeting" value="Geo Targeting" name="geo_targeting">
        <input type="text" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Web Site'){this.value = '';}" onblur="if(this.value == ''){this.value='Web Site';}" id="WebSite" value="Web Site" name="website">        
        <textarea onfocus="if(this.value == 'Message'){this.value = '';}" onblur="if(this.value == ''){this.value='Message';}" id="Message" name="message">Message</textarea>
        <input class="sendBtn" name="submit" type="submit" value="Send" />
    </span>
</form>
```

Javascript Code-

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function validateForm() {
        var x=document.forms["contactForm"]["name"].value;
        if (x==null || x=="") {
            alert("Name must be filled out");
            return false;
        }

        var x=document.forms["contactForm"]["company"].value;
        if (x==null || x=="") {
            alert("Company Name must be filled out");
            return false;
        }

        var x=document.forms["contactForm"]["email"].value;
        var atpos=x.indexOf("@");
        var dotpos=x.lastIndexOf(".");
        if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=x.length) {
            alert("Email must be filled out/Not a valid e-mail address");
            return false;
        }

        var x=document.forms["contactForm"]["message"].value;
        if (x==null || x=="") {
            alert("Message must be filled out");
            return false;
        } 
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I recommend using the `placeholder` attribute instead of setting a default value for inputs

Comment: It is possible to do it using JavaScript alone but it is so much harder (for you to write and for anyone to read...). **jQuery** can certainly be very helpful here.

Comment: Just discovered a possible reason for it not working: although you explicitly return false values for each case where you discover an illegal item you do not provide a positive value in case of success.

Comment: Thanks koala_dev & cars10. placeholder works. Thank you so much for helping me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a very similar problem with trying same-page validation using AJAX queries.  Eventually I figured out that the issue was there was nothing returning TRUE to the onSubmit.  Try this:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            function validateForm()
            {
            var x=document.forms["contactForm"]["name"].value;
            if (x==null || x=="")
              {
              alert("Name must be filled out");
              return false;
              }

            var x=document.forms["contactForm"]["company"].value;
            if (x==null || x=="")
              {
              alert("Company Name must be filled out");
              return false;
              }

            var x=document.forms["contactForm"]["email"].value;
            var atpos=x.indexOf("@");
            var dotpos=x.lastIndexOf(".");
            if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=x.length)
              {
              alert("Email must be filled out/Not a valid e-mail address");
              return false;
              }

            var x=document.forms["contactForm"]["message"].value;
            if (x==null || x=="")
              {
              alert("Message must be filled out");
              return false;
              } 
else {
document.getElementById("contactForm").submit();
            }
}
</script>
```

That solved the issue for me when I was having trouble with it.

also, a handy little trick, instead of saying

```
value="Name"
```

you could try

```
placeholder="Name"
```

otherwise it will pass the value along to the variable and won't validate the form properly.